# System Timeout: on Postback

Tags: c#, linq, exception, timeout

On server before this exception was not coming.. but from last 5-6 days it is coming, the code where this exception is thrown is running succesfully on local system, All other SQL Queries are executing well

```
var varInsertEmailSent = visadc.sp_Update_MailHistory(strCaseNo, intMilestoneid, struserid, intRoleId);
```

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of
>   the operation or the server is not responding.  Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
>   error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details:

> System.Exception: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior
>   to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [Exception: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to
>   completion of the operation or the server is not responding.]
>   .btnsubmit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   C:\Users\Desktop...\wfrmabc.aspx.cs:1849
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +111
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +110
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +10
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>   +36    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +1565

Comment: I have update the question,,, can u please check.. will restarting the server work as it is up from last 3 months without any change

Comment: Hello, try running the stored procedure "sp_Update_MailHistory" on the server, how long it takes to run?

Comment: It is taking less than a second to run this sp in server...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As no help from anyone else so went deep into the issue.. i put a SQL Server Profiler on the Database... i tried to run the query again.. then in the event log i can see that one statement in my SP was taking time and after sometime it was abruptly getting aborted. so when researched i found that my column was not having a nonclustered index which was casuing to take a lot of time to run from client side.

You can also try to find this kind of problems by using profiler on diffrent SPs and RPCs to identify the prob and also to optimize the query
Thank you